# how to get a data from a combobox that I am selecting

Tags: java

I'm using the data that I select from a combo box in a `Jtable`. It retrieves the data, and the value is assigned to other objects that are in the table. I need to take the value from that column in that row for that object. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

this is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    ob = new Impresoras();
    ob.Area = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0);
    ob.nomImpresora = jcb.getSelectedItem().toString();
    impresoras.add(ob);
}

System.out.println(impresoras);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
            ob = new Impresoras();
            ob.Area = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0);
            ob.nomImpresora = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1);
            impresoras.add(ob);

        }`enter code here`
        System.out.println(impresoras); `enter code here`
```